# How do I delete an invincible file, that is not a 0 byte and has an extension?

Tags: help-files

So I have 4 .mkv files I recently downloaded and converted to `.Ogg` by changing the extension. They are YouTube music videos. I tried to get rid of them, but they crash anything and everything that comes in touch with them. I even tried a file shredder, but with no luck, it crashed when trying to delete them. How can I delete them?

Comment: What made you think changing the extension would 'convert' them? What happens if you change it back again?

Comment: @Tetsujin most obvious reason is that OP doesn't know how files work, has .mkv associated with a program that plays both .mkv and .ogg, such as VLC Media player, renamed to .ogg, double clicked it, and VLC media just ignored the fact that it is an ogg and opened it as .mkv as the header of the file suggests and "learned" that you can convert by renaming, which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Have you tried deleting them from the command line ?